# react-webcam not closed after component unmount in react-use-face-detection

Tags: reactjs, camera, face-detection, webcam-capture

I'm try to implement face recognition component using react-use-face-detection and @mediapipe library.When I unmount component react-webcam not closed successfully.How I fix that error?

```
const { webcamRef, boundingBox, isLoading, detected, facesDetected } = useFaceDetection({
    faceDetectionOptions : {
      model: 'short'
    },
    faceDetection: new FaceDetection.FaceDetection({
      locateFile: (file) => {
        return `/face_detection/${file}`
      },
    }),
    camera: ({ mediaSrc, onFrame, width, height }) =>
      new Camera(mediaSrc, {
        onFrame,
        width,
        height,
      }),
  });
```

How I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have rewrited this package you're using to fit some needs of my project but with this I've fixed this issue about camera not unmounting.

In this case I've removed `boundingBox, isLoading, detected and facesDetected` props from the return. If you doesn't need this you can try using it.

[Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-face-detection-hook?activeTab=readme) you can find it.